# UDP port on cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a java server running on cloud foundry. I want to establish a UDP Connection from the client running on local machine.
So how to have the UDP port enabled for the running server on cloud foundry ?

Comment: Not understanding your query... please put some code if possible

Comment: @Jaffer : Actually my java server is listening on a UDP port on which the communication with client will happen. So my question is whether incoming UDP traffic is supported on cloud foundry.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Foundry's gorouter only supports HTTP traffic currently. So if you are deploying your Java server as a Cloud Foundry application instance, and want to access the server through its bound hostname, you will not be able to establish a UDP connection with the server.

(Technically, you could establish the connection if you override the default network security rules and bypass the gorouter altogether, but at this point you would be better off running the server outside of Cloud Foundry)